# Display Flash Message like Gamil in Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hi am developing mvc project using c#.
am thinking to display error messages on view like gmail flash message

lets have a look into my controller

```
public ActionResult CreateEmployeeEducationDetails(EmployeeSuperClass employeeSuperClass, int i = 0)
        {
    if(ModelState.isvalid)
    {
    return "somewhere";
    }
    else
    {
    ViewBag.Message = "Education required";}
        return view("employeeSuperClass");
        }
```

I want to display the viewbag message on view when any errors occurred durinf form post ..message should be displayed like gmail (ex:email has sent) then it has to disappear after sometime please help me your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yeah look into jQuery, that may help you a lot with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toastr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/toastr) JS library to achieve this.

It is very simple to use and configure as per need e.g. you can set position of message, duration to display, etc. For a example,

```
            // Set toastr for error notification and display error 1 at a time
            toastr.options.closeButton = true;
            toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-full-width';
            toastr.options.showMethod = 'slideDown';
            toastr.options.hideMethod = 'slideUp';
            toastr.options.showDuration = '1000';
            toastr.options.hideDuration = '1';
            toastr.clear();
            toastr.error('Your request cannot be processed right now. Please try again later!');
```

For an ajax call, you can invoke the call in success or error method like:

```
                .success(function (result) {
                    //debugger;
                    toastr.success('Order saved successfully!');
                }
```

Update:

After you install the Nuget package, in any view (.cshtml) you like to display the toastr notification, you can add one on any AJAX call. I have added one on document.ready for demo. But you can in any AJAX call success or error method. Do not forget to include js and css (can include in Layout).

**About.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<article>
    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>

    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>

    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>
</article>

<aside>
    <h3>Aside Title</h3>
    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</aside>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        toastr.success('toastr loaded successfully!');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In the view... you can check few example http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Comment: Small doubt where to assign viewbag.message

Comment: In your view when you want to display message just use toastr.error(@ViewBag.Message); This should work, haven't tested though.

Comment: I have installed toastr from nugget package manager console after that I have tried to insert that namespace I coundt finding and I have another confusion is that where do I call tostr.error(@viewbag.Message)I script or in view please explore this and that link does.t have much info of mvc

Comment: I have quickly implemented a new MVC template project and added toastr. PLease see update answer. You need to define toastr notification in script i.e. <script></script> tag.

Comment: yeah working fine am using viewbag.message inside script tag like this <script> toastr.error('@ViewBag.Message')</script> let me know is there any option to use toastr outside script tag means within html contents...thank u

Comment: @user3168867 - Glad it worked for you. Can you accept it as the answer. IMO toastr being JS library has to be used in script env.